# Updating older protobuf in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I got the latest Tensorflow and configured it. When I try to do bazel build it gave me the following warning:

> .....WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in
>   the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a
>   build error in future versions

I ignored the warning and when I try to run now I get the following error:

> In file included from
>   ./tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26:0,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/framework/ops.h:21,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/ops/const_op.h:19,
>                    from ./main.cpp:41: ./tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:12:2:
>   error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc
>   which is  #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc
>   which is   ^
>   ./tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:13:2:
>   error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
>   update  #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
>   update   ^
>   ./tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:14:2:
>   error: #error your headers.  #error your headers.   ^ In file included
>   from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h:26:0,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:26,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:20,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/framework/ops.h:21,
>                    from ./tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/ops/const_op.h:19,
>                    from ./main.cpp:41: ./tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:23:35:
>   fatal error: google/protobuf/arena.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

What does this error mean? I believe this is because of protobuf version mismatch. How do I make it use the system version(which seems to be the newest)?

Thanks for helping.